# Access to guest network from host in Virtual Box

Tags: networking, virtualbox

Suppose I have a host OS (Windows 8.1) and a guest OS (Windows 7), Now I want Windows 8.1 (host) uses the network already established in Windows 7 (guest), Is it possible at all? If so please point me out how I can accomplish it?
Thanks

Comment: Have you looked into the different [VirtualBox Networking Modes](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch06.html#networkingmodes)?  I think what you want can be accomplished with a couple different configurations.